# System file icons are not displaying its original icons for php files on Windows (VS code)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-explorer

So I encountered the system file icons for PHP files on Windows explorer were not displaying the correct icons I am accustomed seeing.
[Displays generic icon instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZN8C.png)

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Goto market place and install
[vscode icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)

then reload

Comment: It still remained the same

Comment: goto view > command palette  >  type "icons " here select vscode icons .  You have a videon on the link i provided in the answer too

Comment: While it did change the icons in VScode, I still got the same generic files on windows explorer. Thanks still though.